# Win32 WH_CBT Hook - close window before it is created

Tags: winapi, hook

I´m a currently running a global hook that watches for a certain window and then closes it with `PostMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);`
The DLL containing the hook:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyFunc(int code,  WPARAM wParam,  LPARAM lParam)  
{    
    switch(code)
    {
    case HCBT_CREATEWND:
        {
            HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
            //GetWindowText(hWnd, wintext, 80)   returns nothing
            //if ( strcmp(wintext, ("Kaspersky Internet Security: license notification")) == 0 )
            //          {    
            //            Beep(70,100);
            //            PostMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
            //          }


            break;

        }
    case HCBT_ACTIVATE:
        {

            HWND hWnd = (HWND)wParam;
            GetWindowText(hWnd, wintext, 80);

            if ( strcmp(wintext, ("Kaspersky Internet Security: license notification")) == 0 )
            {    
                Beep(70,100);
                PostMessage(hWnd,WM_CLOSE,0,0);
            }
            break;    

        }
    }

...
```

As you can see i´m using `GetWindowText(hWnd, wintext, 80)` to determine by window title if the currently activated window is the one to be closed. i´m 
closing the window when it is being activated and not when it is created. I would like to close the window when it is being created, that is when `HCBT_CREATEWND` is true.

The thing is that I can´t use `GetWindowText(hWnd, wintext, 80)` to get the window title and thereby determine if the window should be closed because when `HCBT_CREATEWND` is called the window hasn't been [fully created](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28VS.85%29.aspx) and has no title, `GetWindowText(hWnd, wintext, 80)` returns nothing.

To summarize my question: is it possible to get the title of the window or in any other way determine what kind of window it is, when `HCBT_CREATEWND` is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try [`GetClassName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633582%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead of reading the window text?

It's probably more reliable the reading the window text (internationalization).  An easy way to discover a window's class name is to use the spy++ utility - a handy tutorial is described [here](http://support.citrix.com/article/CTX103137).

Answer (score 0):

The window isn't created yet. Which means you won't be able to call ::GetWindowText(). Instead use the lParam as an LPCBT_CREATEWND. This gives you access to the CREATESTRUCT via a pointer. You can use the lpszName to get access to the window name.

Something like this --

```
CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_CREATEWND:
        {
          LPCBT_CREATEWND lpCreate = (LPCBT_CREATEWND)lParam;
          lpCreate->lpcs->lpszName; // this is the name
          break;
        }
    }
}
```